# Openssl Encrypt/Decrypt does not work with base64

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, base64

I have some openssl code that encrypts and decrypts a file.

Initially I wrote it so the encrypted file is base64 encoded. The problem is certain file sizes are reduced on decryption. i.e I lose upto 16 characters in the decrypted based on the original file

If the file is less that 16 bytes it is fine, greater than that and I start losing characters on decryption with and error on the final decrypt step.

I assumed initially it was a padding issue, but adding padding does bot fix however If I remove the base64 encoding it is fine however.

This is based on open_ssl 1.1.1s

```
int BIO_enc_header(BIO* file, unsigned char* Salt)
{
    RAND_bytes(Salt, SALTSIZE);
    int len=BIO_write(file,MAGIC, MAGIC_SIZE);
    len=BIO_write(file,Salt, SALTSIZE);
    return 0;
}

int BIO_dec_header(BIO* file, unsigned char* Salt)
{
    int mlen = 0;
    char mBuff[MAGIC_SIZE + 1] = { 0 };

    mlen = BIO_read(file,mBuff, MAGIC_SIZE);
    if (mlen == MAGIC_SIZE) {
        /* Check Magic size */
        int salt_len = BIO_read(file,Salt,SALTSIZE);
        if (salt_len != SALTSIZE) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


//#define BASE64 1
int do_crypt_bio(BIO* bio_in, BIO* bio_out, int do_encrypt, unsigned char* szPassword)
{
    int Result = OK;
    unsigned char salt[8] = { 0 };
    int inByte = 0, outByte = 0;
    //int Padding;
#ifdef BASE64
    BIO *b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    if (!b64) {
        return ERROR;
    }
#endif  
#ifdef BASE64
    if (do_encrypt) {
        /*out base64*/
        bio_out = BIO_push(b64, bio_out);
        BIO_set_flags(bio_out, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    }else {
        /* read base 64*/
        bio_in = BIO_push(b64, bio_in);
        BIO_set_flags(bio_in, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    }
#endif
    /* Allow enough space in output buffer for additional block */
    unsigned char inbuf[ENC_BUFF_SIZE+ EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH], outbuf[ENC_BUFF_SIZE + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int inlen, outlen;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx=NULL;
    #define AES_256_KEY_SIZE 32
    unsigned char key[AES_256_KEY_SIZE] = { 0 };
    unsigned char iv[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = { 0 };
    int rounds = 5;

    int Size=EVP_CIPHER_block_size(EVP_aes_256_cbc());

    if (do_encrypt) {
        BIO_enc_header(bio_out, salt);
    }else {
        BIO_dec_header(bio_in, salt);
    }

    if (!EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_256_cbc(), EVP_sha256(), salt, szPassword, strlen((char*)szPassword), rounds, key, iv)) {
#ifdef BASE64
        BIO_free(b64);
#endif
        return ERROR;
    }

    /* Don't set key or IV right away; we want to check lengths */
    ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    if (!ctx) {
#ifdef BASE64
        BIO_free(b64);
#endif
        return ERROR;
    }
    
    int CipherResult=EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL, do_encrypt);
    CipherResult    =EVP_CipherInit_ex(ctx, NULL,              NULL, key,  iv,   do_encrypt);   /* Now we can set key and IV */
    //EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 32);  
    int len;
    for (;;) {
        memset(inbuf, 0, ENC_BUFF_SIZE+EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH);
        inlen = BIO_read(bio_in,inbuf, ENC_BUFF_SIZE);
        //inByte += inlen;
        if (inlen <= 0)break;

        if (!EVP_CipherUpdate(ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)) {
            /* Error */
            Result = ERROR;
            goto error;
        }
        len=BIO_write(bio_out,outbuf,outlen);
        //outByte += outlen;
    }

    int f_len;
    if (!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(ctx, outbuf, &f_len)) {
        /* Error */             
        Result = ERROR;
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        goto error;
    }
    len= BIO_write(bio_out, outbuf, f_len);
    //outByte += f_len;
    len = len;
    
error:
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
#ifdef BASE64
    BIO_free(b64);  
#endif
    return Result;
}

int EncryptFile(char* input, char *encrypted,char* password)
{
    int Result = OK;
    BIO* bio_in = BIO_new_file(input, "rb");
    if (!bio_in) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    BIO* bio_out = BIO_new_file(encrypted, "wb+");
    if (!bio_out) {
        BIO_free(bio_in);
        return ERROR;
    }
    Result=do_crypt_bio(bio_in, bio_out, 1, (unsigned char*)password);
    BIO_free(bio_in);
    BIO_free(bio_out);
    return Result;
}


int DecryptFile(char* encrypted, char* output, char* password)
{
    int Result = OK;
    BIO* bio_in = BIO_new_file(encrypted, "rb");
    if (!bio_in) {
        return ERROR;
    }
    BIO* bio_out = BIO_new_file(output, "wb+");
    if (!bio_out) {
        BIO_free(bio_in);
        return ERROR;
    }
    Result=do_crypt_bio(bio_in, bio_out, 0, (unsigned char*)password);
    BIO_free(bio_in);
    BIO_free(bio_out);
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: My eyes are starting to hurt, but worth pointing out that when you loading a b64 filter on an out stream it is important that bio stack be `BIO_flush`'ed before being freed.